# Why can @decorator not decorate a staticmethod or a classmethod?

Tags: python, decorator

Why can `decorator` not decorate a staticmethod or a classmethod?

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def print_function_name(function, *args):
    print '%s was called.' % function.func_name
    return function(*args)

class My_class(object):
    @print_function_name
    @classmethod
    def get_dir(cls):
        return dir(cls)

    @print_function_name
    @staticmethod
    def get_a():
        return 'a'
```

Both `get_dir` and `get_a` result in `AttributeError: <'classmethod' or 'staticmethod'>,  object has no attribute '__name__'`.

Why does `decorator` rely on the attribute `__name__` instead of the attribute `func_name`? (Afaik all functions, including classmethods and staticmethods, have the `func_name` attribute.)

Edit: I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: Why are you calling function(*args) INSIDE the decorator?  It's job is to simply return a function (in your case, unmodified).

Comment: gahooa: because that's one way 'decorator' (what he imports, not the language construct) works, see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator.

Comment: @taldor you have decorator module in py 2.6 ?

Comment: @mykhal: I installed it separately.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It works when `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` are the top-most decorators:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def print_function_name(function, *args):
    print '%s was called.' % function.func_name
    return function(*args)

class My_class(object):
    @classmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_dir(cls):
        return dir(cls)
    @staticmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_a():
        return 'a'
```

Comment: As a rule, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` apply a special kind of magic and have to be called last.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not 100% interchangeable. Moving the builtin decorators up may affect characteristics of the result method itself, e.g. if `print_function_name` was a decorating class, the outstanding type of the result method would be affected by the overruling builtin decorator

Answer (score 91):

`classmethod` and `staticmethod` return [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html), not functions.  Most decorators are not designed to accept descriptors.

Normally, then, you must apply `classmethod` and `staticmethod` last when using multiple decorators.  And since decorators are applied in "bottom up" order, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` normally should be top-most in your source.

Like this:

```
class My_class(object):
    @classmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_dir(cls):
        return dir(cls)

    @staticmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_a():
        return 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted?

```
def print_function_name(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('%s was called.' % function.__name__)
        return function(*args)
    return wrapper

class My_class(object):
    @classmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_dir(cls):
        return dir(cls)

    @staticmethod
    @print_function_name
    def get_a():
        return 'a'
```

Comment: I'm not sure you realized, but the "decorator" package he's using does the same thing as the construct with "wrapper".  The only difference between your snippets is the order of applying the decorators in My_class.  You might clarify that in the answer to explain why it fixes things.

Comment: Thanks for a correction. I was playing with the problem in py3k, where the decorator module is missing. I meant my reply to be the quick one, and was sure that someone will post the better answer with detailed explanation

Comment: @(Peter Hansen) .. however, there's no decorator module in python 2.6 either