# How to create a Python class decorator that is able to wrap instance, class and static methods?

Tags: python, reflection, decorator, instrumentation

I'd like to create a Python **class decorator** (*) that would be able to seamlessly wrap all method types the class might have: instance, class and static.

This is the code I have for now, with the parts that break it commented:

```
def wrapItUp(method):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "This method call was wrapped!"
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

dundersICareAbout = ["__init__", "__str__", "__repr__"]#, "__new__"]

def doICareAboutThisOne(cls, methodName):
    return (callable(getattr(cls, methodName))
            and (not (methodName.startswith("__") and methodName.endswith("__"))
            or methodName in dundersICareAbout))

def classDeco(cls):
    myCallables = ((aname, getattr(cls, aname)) for aname in dir(cls) if doICareAboutThisOne(cls, aname))
    for name, call in myCallables:
        print "*** Decorating: %s.%s(...)" % (cls.__name__, name)
        setattr(cls, name, wrapItUp(call))
    return cls

@classDeco
class SomeClass(object):

    def instanceMethod(self, p):
        print "instanceMethod: p =", p

    @classmethod
    def classMethod(cls, p):
        print "classMethod: p =", p

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod(p):
        print "staticMethod: p =", p


instance = SomeClass()
instance.instanceMethod(1)
#SomeClass.classMethod(2)
#instance.classMethod(2)
#SomeClass.staticMethod(3)
#instance.staticMethod(3)
```

I'm having two issues trying to make this work:

- When iterating over all callables, how do I find out if it is of an instance, class or static type?
- How to I overwrite the method with a proper wrapped version of it that is invoked correctly for each of those cases?

Currently, this code generates different `TypeError`s depending on what commented snippet is uncommented, like:

- `TypeError: unbound method wrapped() must be called with SomeClass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`
- `TypeError: classMethod() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

---

(*): The same problem is much simpler if you're [decorating the methods directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987919/why-can-decorator-not-decorate-a-staticmethod-or-a-classmethod).

Comment: It will be fun to see how different developers have handled this same, complicated, issue.

Comment: @wberry: yeah, already I'm reading through current answers and noticed it'll be hard to choose the "right" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because methods are wrappers for functions, to apply a decorator to a method on a class after the class has been constructed, you have to:

1. Extract the underlying function from the method using its `im_func` attribute.
2. Decorate the function.
3. Re-apply the wrapper.
4. Overwrite the attribute with the wrapped, decorated function.

It is difficult to distinguish a `classmethod` from a regular method once the `@classmethod` decorator has been applied; both kinds of methods are of type `instancemethod`. However, you can check the `im_self` attribute and see whether it is `None`. If so, it's a regular instance method; otherwise it's a `classmethod`.

Static methods are simple functions (the `@staticmethod` decorator merely prevents the usual method wrapper from being applied). So you don't have to do anything special for these, it looks like.

So basically your algorithm looks like this:

1. Get the attribute.
2. Is it callable? If not, proceed to the next attribute.
3. Is its type `types.MethodType`? If so, it is either a class method or an instance method.

   - If its `im_self` is `None`, it is an instance method.  Extract the underlying function via the `im_func` attribute, decorate that, and re-apply the instance method: `meth = types.MethodType(func, None, cls)`
   - If its `im_self` is not `None`, it is a class method. Exctract the underlying function via `im_func` and decorate that. Now you have to reapply the `classmethod` decorator but you can't because `classmethod()` doesn't take a class, so there's no way to specify what class it will be attached to. Instead you have to use the instance method decorator: `meth = types.MethodType(func, cls, type)`. Note that the `type` here is the actual built-in, `type`.
4. If its type is not `types.MethodType` then it is a static method or other non-bound callable, so just decorate it.
5. Set the new attribute back onto the class.

These change somewhat in Python 3 -- unbound methods are functions there, IIRC. In any case this will probably need to be completely rethought there.

Comment: Chose this one as the answer as it clearly explains the underlying problem. Thanks and sorry for the long delay!

Answer (score 4):

There is an undocumented function, `inspect.classify_class_attrs`, which can tell you which attributes are classmethods or staticmethods. Under the hood, it uses `isinstance(obj, staticmethod)` and `isinstance(obj, classmethod)` to classify static and class methods. Following that pattern, this works in both Python2 and Python3:

```
def wrapItUp(method,kind='method'):
    if kind=='static method':
        @staticmethod
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return _wrapped(*args,**kwargs)
    elif kind=='class method':
        @classmethod
        def wrapped(cls,*args, **kwargs):
            return _wrapped(*args,**kwargs)                
    else:
        def wrapped(self,*args, **kwargs):
            return _wrapped(self,*args,**kwargs)                                
    def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("This method call was wrapped!")
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
def classDeco(cls):
    for name in (name
                 for name in dir(cls)
                 if (callable(getattr(cls,name))
                     and (not (name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'))
                          or name in '__init__ __str__ __repr__'.split()))
                 ):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        obj = cls.__dict__[name] if name in cls.__dict__ else method
        if isinstance(obj, staticmethod):
            kind = "static method"
        elif isinstance(obj, classmethod):
            kind = "class method"
        else:
            kind = "method"
        print("*** Decorating: {t} {c}.{n}".format(
            t=kind,c=cls.__name__,n=name))
        setattr(cls, name, wrapItUp(method,kind))
    return cls

@classDeco
class SomeClass(object):
    def instanceMethod(self, p):
        print("instanceMethod: p = {}".format(p))
    @classmethod
    def classMethod(cls, p):
        print("classMethod: p = {}".format(p))
    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod(p):
        print("staticMethod: p = {}".format(p))

instance = SomeClass()
instance.instanceMethod(1)
SomeClass.classMethod(2)
instance.classMethod(2)
SomeClass.staticMethod(3)
instance.staticMethod(3)
```