# Python Decorate all methods of subclass, and provide means to override

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am working on finding a way to reduce boilerplate decorators.  We have a lot of classes that use a @decorate.  For example:

```
class MyClass(Base):
     @decorate
     def fun1(self):
         pass
     @decorate
     def fun2(self):
         pass
     def fun3(self):
         pass
```

I want to make it so by default the decorator is there, unless someone specifies otherwise.

---

I use this code to do the autowrap

```
from functools import wraps

def myDecorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print 'enter'
            ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print 'leave'
        except:
            print 'exception'
            ret = None

        return ret

    return decorator

class TestDecorateAllMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local):
        for attr in local:
            value = local[attr]
            if callable(value):
                local[attr] = myDecorator(value)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, local)

class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = TestDecorateAllMeta

    def test_print2(self, val):
        print val

    def test_print(self, val):
        print val

c = TestClass()
c.test_print1("print 1")
c.test_print2("print 2")
```

My question are:

1. Is there a better way to accompish auto-decorating?
2. How can I go about overriding?

Ideally my end solution would be something like:

```
class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = TestDecorateAllMeta

    def autowrap(self):
        print("Auto wrap")

    @dont_decorate
    def test_dont_decorate(self, val):
        print val
```

**Edit**

To speak to one of the comments below, since classess are callable instead of doing

```
if callable(value):
```

It should read:

```
if isinstance(value,types.FunctionType)
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. Unless there's a lot of boilerplace (a dozen nontrivial lines per method), I'd shy away from metaclass magic. Heck, even then I'd prefer a simpler solution whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than making the user of my class specify a `__metaclass__` attribute I would just have them derive from my base class that defines it.  No need to expose the plumbing unnecessarily.

Other than that, looks good, though.  Your `@dont_decorate` function decorator can be implemented by setting an attribute on the original function, which your class decorator then detects and skips the decoration if it is present.

```
def dont_decorate(func):
    func._dont_decorate = True
    return func
```

Then in your metaclass, where you now have the line `if callable(value):` just put:

```
if callable(value) and not hasttr(value, "_dont_decorate"):
```

As an aside, *classes are callable* so if you don't want inner classes decorated, you should probably check for functions using `isinstance()` rather than `callable()`.

If you are interested in more explicit alternatives, you might take a look at [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185375/how-to-create-a-python-class-decorator-that-is-able-to-wrap-instance-class-and/) where someone wanted to do essentially the same thing using a class decorator. Unfortunately, this is a good bit more complicated because the methods are already wrapped by the time the decorator sees them.

Comment: So the reason I put __meta__ class in the child class was so it only decorates the members of the child class.  If i put meta in the parent it will decorate all function types... do you have an easy way to detect if the Function being called belongs to the subclass?

Comment: You could put `@dont_decorate` on all the functions in the parent class.  :-)

Comment: That gets annoying :) and I believe thats how I got to this point... I could create an intermediate class...

Comment: Or a cleaner way: declare one class with the methods, then a second class that inherits from that and defines `__metaclass__`. Then have users inherit from the second class.

Comment: Yes, you wrote your "intermediate class" comment while I was writing my second one!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice.  I updated above to show the isinstance vs callable.  Just so people can see what you were talking about.

Comment: Thought of a way to eliminate that intermediate class: have your metaclass check to see if your base class's name is in `globals()` before applying the decorator. If it's not, then it's being used on the base class and you shouldn't decorate.

Comment: Not sure if i follow?  You talking about a if not globals().has_key("<base_class_name>")  ?

Comment: Yeah... `if "base_class_name" in globals()` then apply the decorator ... if the base class name is *not* in `globals()` it means we're defining the base class *right now,* and so should not apply the decorator.