# Decorating classes and classmethods

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming, decorator

I want to wrap one of the methods of class in decorator. If this necessary, my class is django class based view.

First type of implementation is wrap method by *method_decorator*:

```
class MyView(View):
   template_name = "index.html"
   @method_decorator(login_required):
   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ok, this works. But I don't want to every time overwrite method *dispatch*.

Second way - mixins and multiple inheritance.

```
class LoginRequiredView(object):
   @method_decorator(login_required):
   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class MyView(LoginRequiredView, View):
   template_name = "index.html"
```

This works too. But if I want to use multiple decorators, it is required to list all mixins in parents. It is not very good for me.

I want next:

```
@viewdecorator(login_required)
class MyView(LoginRequiredView, View):
   template_name = "index.html"
```

And my question is how to implement *viewdecorator*. I try to write this:

```
def viewdecorator(decorator):
    def wrap(cls):
        dispatch = getattr(cls, 'dispatch', None)
        if dispatch:
            setattr(cls, 'dispatch', method_decorator(decorator))
        return cls
    return wrap
```

But resulting cls in this decorator don't contains original *classmethods* and *classonlymethods*. I guess about a reason such behavior.

How to write *viewdecorator* to *classmethods* will be presented in resulting cls?

UPD: I understood how this work and below actual working code with example

```
def viewdecorator(decorator):
    def wrap(cls):
        getattribute = cls.__getattribute__

        def newgetattr(cls, name):
            attr = getattribute(cls, name)
            if name == 'dispatch':
                return decorator(method_decorator(attr))
            return attr 

        cls.__getattribute__ = newgetattr
        return cls
    return wrap

@viewdecorator(login_required)
@viewdecorator(csrf_exempt)
class EntriesMyList(EntriesList):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Comment: So what you're saying is if `dispatch` is a `classmethod`, then your `viewdecorator` won't work? `classmethod` must be the top-most decorators, but maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: `viewdecorator` looks good to me, I don't understand what you meant by "resulting cls in this decorator don't contains original classmethods and classonlymethods"? It definitely contains all the methods. Also you need to set `'dispatch'` to `method_decorator(decorator)(dispatch).`

Comment: @simonzack No, you can place `@classmethod` anywhere.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm not sure about that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987919/why-can-decorator-not-decorate-a-staticmethod-or-a-classmethod

Comment: Ok, in viewdecorator cls does not contain methods as_view, dispatch. Why?

Comment: @simonzack I see, good example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org). This library contains login required mixin

```
from django.views.generic import View
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class SimpleView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    pass
```

For correct style you don't need decorators for CBV. If you need some custom view permissions implement you logic in `dispatch` view method.

Comment: As result I will get a long list of parents for view. Not very good. In the end of question I wrote useful solution.