# python decorator for class method and static method?

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to write a decorator for an instance method, as follows:

```
from functools import wraps

def plus_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return 1 + f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@plus_decorator
def return_i(i):
    return i

class A(object):
    @plus_decorator
    def return_i(self, i):
        return i

    @plus_decorator
    @classmethod
    def return_i_class(cls, i):
        return i

    @plus_decorator
    @staticmethod
    def return_i_static(i):
        return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print return_i(1)
    a = A()
    print a.return_i(1)
    print A.return_i_class(1)
    print A.return_i_static(1)
```

However, it pops up the error:

```
AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I am wondering why the decorator does not work on `classmethod` and `staticmethod`. I think the decorator mostly just passes all the parameters it receives to the wrapper, and only modifies the result. How can I modify the decorator to make it work for `classmethod` and `staticmethod`?

Comment: What does your callsite look like?

Comment: This works fine. You aren't creating an instance of `A()` to call it, e.g. `a = A(); a.return_i(1)`. Perhaps you also need `@classmethod`?

Comment: Oops. The original error I met was decorator for class method, and somehow I messed up the callsite for instance method. Let me change the content.

Answer (score 9):

Just flip the order.  Put the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` on the outside, and your decorator (which uses `@wraps`, and therefore needs a bare function) on the inside.

```
@classmethod
@plus_decorator
def return_i_class(cls, i):
    return i
```

Answer (score 3):

Try reversing.

It will work when @staticmethod and @classmethod are top-most decorators as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1989025/6815711)

Because your decorator expects a function but both the other decorators return descriptor objects.